# How to find node parents information in NetworkX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, networkx, jsnetworkx

I have a NetworkX graph like following.

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge('a', 'b')
g.add_edge('b', 'c')
g.add_edge('b', 'd')
g.add_edge('b', 'e')
g.add_edge('e', 'f')
```

I have a Python function called `getHop` and it takes two parameters. One is `node` and other one is `hop`.

```
getHop(node, hop):
```

If node is `f` and hop is `1` then `getHop` should return parent node(s) of `f`. In this case it is `e`.

If node is `f` and hop is `2` then `getHop` should return grand parent node(s) of `f`. In this case it is `b`.

If node is `f` and hop is `3` then `getHop` should return great grandparent node(s) of `f`. In this case it is `a`.

How can I implement the above-mentioned scenario in NetworkX. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a function in the networkx library that allows you to do that but it should be fairly straight forward to build through a loop in a function, see example below that should yield your result:

Keep in mind that the predecessors function returns an iterator so it was simpler to insert the result of the function in a list and obtain the first value https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html

```
def getHop(node, hop):
    if hop == 1: 
        result = list(g.predecessors(node))[0]
    else: 
        for hop_element in range(hop): 
            if hop_element == 0: 
                temp_result = list(g.predecessors(node))[0]
            elif hop_element +1 == hop:
                result = list(g.predecessors(temp_result))[0]
            else: 
                temp_result = list(g.predecessors(temp_result))[0]
    return result
```